# Using Custom OmniAuth Providers Images Not Loading

Tags: omniauth, gitlab

I've successfully created my first OmniAuth strategy and packaged it as a gem.  I added this to the Gemfile in GitLab and ran `bundle install --path vendor/bundle --no-deployment`, which installed the gem.

Next I updated the gitlab.yml file by duplicating the section we have for GitHub and completing it with our own values.

As directed by the GitLab reference instructions at https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/5-3-stable/doc/install/installation.md
I then added two image files to the `vendor/assets/images/authbuttons` directory, all lowercase in the format of "strategyname_32.png" and "strategyname_64.png".

Finally I restarted GitLab and on the login page I now see a button for our new provider (which works, yea!) but the images that I uploaded aren't used for the button, instead a basic grey button is being used.

I cannot find anything in any of the logs indicating that it's not able to find the image files and I've tried renaming the files using various cases since this is on a Ubuntu system.
I also executed a `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` but that didn't seem to make a difference.

Am I missing something to get this provider to be represented by our image instead of the basic HTML button on the login page?  I don't see any steps that I've missed in the instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is "by design" that additional providers load as an HTML button and don't use a graphic placed in the path `vendor/assets/images/authbuttons` as mentioned in the installation instructions.  This is because only providers listed in the `default_providers()` [function](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/98cf0ae3384afa34a417766f46a7b3171dc40279/app/helpers/oauth_helper.rb#L7) within the `app/helpers/oauth_helper.rb` use images in the `vendor/assets/images/authbuttons` directory to display on the login page.

So for me to successfully use my custom omniauth provider and have a graphic element for the login link on the GItLab login page I did the following:

- Stop GitLab `sudo service gitlab stop`
- placed my two graphics in the `vendor/assets/images/authbuttons` directory
- added my provider as one of the default providers in the `default_providers()` function of the `app/helpers/oauth_helper.rb` file
- Added a section for my provider in `config/gitlab.yml` with the `client_id` and `client_secret`
- Added my omniauth strategy to the `Gemfile` file
- Installed the gem from the GitLab root directory using `sudo -u git -H bundle install --without development test postgres --path vendor/bundle --no-deploy`
- Precompiled the assets from the GitLab root directory using `sudo -u git -H rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`
- Start GitLab `sudo service gitlab start`